# fatal error detected by the JRE - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: c++, jvm, java-native-interface

My C++ JNI code which consists of :

1. finding the java class to be used
2. Calling the constructor
3. Calling the init function of the class : i tried using the jclass returned by the FindClass function (JCTerminalClass) and the jclass returned by GetObjectClass(obj).

   ```
   1. JCTerminalClass = env->FindClass("com/ibm/jc/terminal/RemoteJCTerminal");

   2. mid = env->GetMethodID(JCTerminalClass, "<init>", "()V");

   if(mid !=0) {        
       obj = env->NewObject(JCTerminalClass, mid);
       cout << "Object created with constructor" << endl;
   }

   3.jclass clss = env->GetObjectClass(obj);  
   mid = env->GetMethodID(JCTerminalClass,"init","(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/ibm/jc/JCTerminal;");
   /*  or   */ 
   mid = env->GetMethodID(clss,"init","(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/ibm/jc/JCTerminal;");
   obj = (jobject)env->CallObjectMethod(obj, mid, "someString");
   ```

In both cases i get no errors during compilation and the execution goes well until the CallObjectMethod is called and we get the following error :

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000028120b6, pid=4064, tid=1576
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    j  com.ibm.jc.terminal.RemoteJCTerminal.init(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/ibm/jc/JCTerminal;+8
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:

Oh and i think it's worth noting that JCTerminalClass and clss do not have the same values : respectively 0x1dfec60 and 0x1dfec50 ... any idea why might that be ? since we're talking about the same class ...

Plus i think the obj is well instantiated i tried printing some of its static final values ...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I would start by stopping my program at the entry point, view the dis-assembly at memory address 0x00000000028120b6, and see what piece of code was generating the exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `"someString"` argument. `init` method expects an argument to be a Java object.
Use `NewStringUTF` JNI function to construct a `jstring` from `char *`

Comment: BTW, this is not your first question on JNI basics. I suggest you read JNI documentation carefully or at least study some JNI examples before asking StackOverflow about every single function you misuse.

Comment: Thank you again apangin ! it's true this is not the first time, but i find the oracle doc not explanatory, good documentation and examples can be found in e-books but they are not always complete ...
I'm a taker of good links if you suggest any !